# How can I write an mt4 indicator that draws a rectangle and horizontal lines over first 6 hours of hourly candles

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I am a quite new to mql4 coding. I would like to know how I write an indicator that does the following, based on the image below:

1. Draw a rectangle over the current day hour chart that covers the highest and lowest price points of the first 6 hours (candles)
2. Draw two horizontal lines along the highest and lowest points found 1.

Please note that 1. and 2. should be based strictly on the hourly period and shouldn't vary with the selected period.

I believe I'm suppose to be using `ObjectCreate()` with `OBJ_RECTANGLE` and `OBJ_HLINE` but the whole concept is quite new to me. I would really appreciate some assistance.

[image]

Comment: Would you like us to code for you? Or maybe you have some detailed questions on how to make sure N(=6) hours left since day start, how to see day start, how to compute High and low of some interval, how to draw objects using the known High, Low and dates? Your detailed questions on programming will bring fast reply, a project should be assigned to a freelancer instead.

Comment: @DanielKniaz There are a number of things I'm trying to understand at the same time. That's why I asked the question in such a manner. For example, I tried getting the following code I found online to work to get an idea how to draw a horizontal line but I couldn't. https://pastebin.com/ZsEd2fzW. Not that I want any one to complete a project for me or anything of that sort, but understanding how a horizontal line and rectangle are drawn would serve as a good foundation for me to find my way around.

Comment: code is ok probably but of course it is not optimized. anyway, you can use it as a good start. You have a function to draw a horizontal line with name and level as inputs. So what would you need next?

Comment: @DanielKniaz the indicator does not display the horizontal lines. I see nothing when I put it on a currency pair.

Comment: Do you mean you used the code you mentioned? have you chosen drawUp=true, drawDn=true, color != clrNone ? do you see any errors in the expert log?